# I used a custom field for header image and can't get it to show up on posts

Tags: custom-field

I have recreated it in Wordpress and am working offline. Everything is good and works the way I want it to. I have does this in order to add a blog. To get the image above the content I used custom fields. When the blog page is a static page it works fine but when I set it be the post page the image does not show up. The container for the image shows up, just not the image. Here is the code for the beginning of the single.php and index.php up until the loop starts.

```
       <?php
       get_sidebar(); ?>

       <?php

        $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, img, true);
        ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="img"/>


        </div>

<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

I have read a few things about calling the custom field outside the loop but I'm not sure how to do this or if that is even correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty wonky (I would never do it), but it should work if you access the global.

```
    global $post;
    $image = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'img', true);

    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="img"/>
```

Comment: Can't you use `global $post` instead of `global $wp_query` then use `get_post_meta` ?